# Stopping power (particle radiation)

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation

Could anyone explain to me how a particle can lose energy due to to ionisation in matter (soft collisions-Bethe formula).

If the particle feels coulomb force with electrons in matter, it should not lose enegy due to simitry (the Hamiltonial does not depend on time in a radial potential).

For example I would expect an electron first slow down due to repulsion from another electron but once it passes in would accelerate due to that repulsion (I am not sure that I understood the concept correctly).

Comment: Why do you think that symmetry means you can't lose energy? Consider the Rutherford experiment - those alpha particles that scatter off of Au nuclei most certainly do lose energy in the lab frame. And the potential is the same Coulomb potential that leads to electronic stopping. Why can't one fast moving particle impart small amounts of energy to lots of electrons?

Answer (score 1):

Particles belong to the realm of quantum mechanics, and quantum mechanics is not billiard balls, charged or not.

As a charged particle meets atoms there are quantum mechanical  interactions: atom+particle scattering. These can be elastic, directions is changed and in the lab some momentum tranferred,  or  inelastic raising an electron to a higher energy level so the incoming particle loses an increment. It is a consecutive process , interacting with atoms and lattice locations until it loses its momentum completely.

For details please refer to [this article.](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2013-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to say this process of ionisation resembles the photoelectric effect with particles insted of photons?

Comment: well, it is a statistical effect involving consecutive quantum mecahnical interactions. The photoelectric is also seen statistically with the lower possible limit for extracting  an electron. But stopping power depends on the mass and the charge of the particle for a given material. not a very good analogy. I do not think one could use it to argue quantization of atoms. Even classically there would be radiation in the field of atoms that would slow a classical track. One would have to model the classical and compare to the qm

Comment: I ment the idea of a charged particle (electron for example) as a result of "collision" tears another electron from its orbit and by that ionising the atom, its similar to a photon that tears an electron from its orbit as well.